# How and where can I post a video for review of Blender users, that shows my students work?

Tags: video

This spring I taught 3D Animation at Calhoun Community College.  I posted several questions here that were very helpful.  My 4 advanced students completed a project that was on time and exceeded my expectations.  I thought that some of you advanced users might enjoy seeing it and the back story about what motivated the production.

If that is the case, where might I post a link to the Youtube version of it?

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?10-Finished-Projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this site is not a forum for posting or sharing work. I'd recommend posting it on [BlenderArtists.org](http://BlenderArtists.org).

Answer (score 1):

The Blender subreddit is also quite popular.

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/